# Can I search devices and computers in the same wifi network?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I'm trying to search for devices and equipment which are connected to the same wifi network to which my device is connected. I using the following code but until now I haven't had any success

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        URL[] urls;
        URL proveUrl;
        HttpURLConnection con;
        private boolean next(int position){
            if (position++ < urls.length){
                try {
                    proveUrl = new URL(urls[position].getHost() + ":36000");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, "Malformed URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            wifiManager.getScanResults().toArray(urls);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                proveUrl =new URL(urls[0].getHost() + ":36000");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, "Malformed URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return prove();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            direccionIp = proveUrl.getHost();
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        private Boolean prove(){
            int position = 0;
            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) proveUrl.openConnection();
                BufferedInputStream req = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (next(position)){
                    position++;
                    prove();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Somebody knows how to do this? Thanks